# Can I use my acer chromebook 11 charger to power my raspberry pi 4b?

Tags: alternative-power

What does it mean when my acer chromebook 11 charger says "5v ⎓ 3a / 9v ⎓ 3a / 15v ⎓ 3a / 20v ⎓ 2.25a" on the ac adapter?
I want it to output 5 volts with 3 amps, but I am confused at why it also has the other options afterward. I am thinking about using this for my Raspberry pi 4b. Will this sub for the offical power supply?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the image of the ac adapter:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I power a RPi 4 model B via a 5V/2A fast charging adapter?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109683/can-i-power-a-rpi-4-model-b-via-a-5v-2a-fast-charging-adapter)

Comment: Variants of this have been asked MANY times. The Answer remains the same - no one knows!

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is an auto-charger. You should not use this types of chargers to work with Pi. If accidentally the the voltage rise your Pi would fry.Use a 5V 2.5A adapter if you can manage.

Answer (score 1):

3 amps at 5 volts should be enough to power any Pi.

Whether your charger can produce this or not is impossible to answer without the actual charger or clear photos.

Comment: I have added a clear image of the ac adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This means, that the charger can work in any of this options. The default option is usually one with the least power (3V/3A in your case). Then the charger is connected to the device, they can communicate by data wires and, if necessary, increase the power (obviously, by request from the device).

Comment: So, does that mean that using the charger should work fine?

Comment: Yes, that *should* work fine.

Comment: However, "there is a strong belief, that standards are something that people obey". If vendor of your charger for any reason made another default, it _can_ be harmful. If you have free USB-C female connector, you can measure the supplied voltage directly. Moreover, you can check rpi's docs for power schematics and read datasheets of its ICs (for max input voltage).

Answer (score 0):

The higher voltages on your power supply should only be activated after USB-PD negotiation has taken place. USB-PD stands for USB Power Delivery which is the official standard for the negotiation of power delivery over USB. The Raspberry Pi 4 does not support USB-PD and therefore will not negotiate to a higher voltage. I can't guarantee anything, because I couldn't find if the power supply supports USB-PD.

*If* it follows standards, it *should* not go over 5V and work just fine for your Raspberry Pi.